# Can I get visas for Nigeria and Ghana in Senegal?

Tags: visas, ghana, senegal, nigeria

I am traveling multiple countries soon, but my travel document is taking longer than expected. I anticipate that I can get the visa for at least the first country before my departure. Would I be able to get the visas for the following countries in the first one I am visiting?

I am an asylee in the US and have applied for a Travel document with the USCIS, but it is taking longer than expected.

I will be traveling to **Senegal**, **Nigeria** and **Ghana** this summer. I am anticipating that I will not have the time to get the visas for Nigeria and Ghana before my travel date.

Can I get those from their respective embassies in **Senegal**?

Comment: This VERY much depends on which country you're in, which you want the visa for, and what your citizenship is.  Can you please clarify by editing your question?

Answer (score 2):

The [website of the Ghanaian Embassy in Dakar](http://www.ghanaembdakar.com/Visas) is down at the moment, but according to Google's [cached version](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:87Qdq6RNs_oJ%3awww.ghanaembdakar.com/Visas+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=za) it states:

> REQUIREMENTS FOR VISA APPLICANTS
>
> - Should be Officially Resident in Senegal

The [website of the Nigerian Embassy](http://www.nigeriandakar.sn/visas.html) does not list any such requirement; I suggest you contact them to determine whether it is allowed.